# Getting previous months in php

Tags: php, date, select

I need to display 3 month from the previous month in php

Here is what I have tried so far

```
<select style='width: 112px;' name='PayMonth'>
<option name="PayMonth" value=''>Select Month</option>   
<?php
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
$allmonth = date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")))
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));?>
</option>
<?php
}?>
```

This will display all months

But how can I display on 3 months from current month

i.e.,

**If current month is april it should show Feb, Mar, Apr**

**If current month is jan it should show nov, dec, jan**

I tried..

```
<?php

$month = date("m");

?>
```

But in the loop I am confused with

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= $month; $i++)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `$month = date("m");` Then your forloop should be

```
for($i = $month-3 ; $i <= $month; $i++)
```

Sidenote :

As you are using

```
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));?>
```

You may get -1, -2 inside the values. So you should change

```
<option value="<?php echo date("m",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y"))); ?>" ><?php echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));?>
```

To get

```
<select style='width: 112px;' name='PayMonth'>
  <option name="PayMonth" value=''>Select Month</option>   
  <option value="11" >November  </option>
  <option value="12" >December  </option>
  <option value="01" >January  </option>
  <option value="02" >February  </option>   
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy as cake:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
```

And you can substitute -1 with the number of your choice:

```
<?php
foreach(range(-1,-3,-1) as $value) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(sprintf("first day of %d month", $value)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

to get last month.

You can put -2 or -3 to get 2 months ago or 3 months ago also.

Substitute 'm' with the format of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo date('M', strtotime('0 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-1 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-2 month'));
echo date('M', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration that you will get wrong results when using months back using the current day - on every 31st day the month.

Try this instead:

```
<?
$monthsBack = 3;
// we need to do set day to middle of the month,
// otherwise "-x month" will return wrong results on the 31st of each month:
$now =  mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 15, date("Y"));

for ($i1=0; $i1<$monthsBack; $i1++) {
    $displayDate = strtotime("-{$monthsBack} month", $now);
    echo '<option value="'.date("m", $displayDate).'" >'.date("F", $displayDate).'</option>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Today is 2015-02-30
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last month'));
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).